# Normalize values to a range between -1 and 1

Tags: c#, math

I want to process joystick values in such a way that the "normalized" values lay between -1 and 1 (including numbers with decimal places, for example 0.0129).

Specifically, I'm dealing with the input a Wiimote Controller stick.

The X axis has a range between 35 and 228, and the Y axis has range between 27 and 220.

The center for both is 128.

Now I would like to make it so that a value of 35 on the X axis would result in -1, the value of 128 should results in 0, and the value of 228 should result in 1.

Is there a special way to do with this?

The best I could come up with was:

```
public float[] GetStickNormalizedDataXY() 
{
    float[] ret = new float[2];

    ret[0] = _stick[0];
    ret[0] -= 35;
    ret[1] = stick[1];
    ret[1] -= 27;

    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    {
        ret[x] /= 193f;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

But my results only vary between 0 and 1, so I guess I must be doing something wrong here.

Comment: Are you looking for ranges to return -1, 0 or 1?  [35-127] = -1, [128 - something] = 0, etc or just those specific values?

Comment: @NathanChampion Specific values, not just -1, 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
float[] NormalizeStickData(float[] stickData)
{
    return new[]
        { 
            Normalize(stickData[0], 35, 228, 128, -1, 1, 0),
            Normalize(stickData[1], 27, 220, 128, -1, 1, 0)
        };
}

float Normalize(float value, float oldMin, float oldMax, float oldMid, float newMin, float newMax, float newMid)
{
    if (value < oldMid)
        return Interpolate(value, oldMin, oldMid, newMin, newMid);
    else if (value > oldMid)
        return Interpolate(value, oldMid, oldMax, newMid, newMax);
    else
        return newMid;
}

float Interpolate(float value, float oldMin, float oldMax, float newMin, float newMax)
{
    return (float)(newMin + (newMax - newMin)*(value - oldMin)/(oldMax - oldMin));
}
```

[Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ssGS2r)

Comment: The interpolation form is weird, you can write it simply `newMin + (newMax - newMin)*(value - oldMin)/(oldMax - oldMin)`

Comment: @AntonínLejsek yeah that would be true if the question would've been to just map a point in a number range to another range, but he also wants a variable midpoint in the number range.

Comment: Your `Interpolate` function does exactly that - map a point in a number range (oldMin..oldMax) to another range (newMin..newMax).

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Sorry, i misunderstood you. You're obviously correct. I'm going to update my answer with your easier formular. I just googled for a interpolation function and ended up with this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a nice smooth function that takes on specific output values at *3* specific input values, the simplest thing to do is to use a quadratic polynomial.  That means something of the form out=Ax^2 + Bx + C, where out is the output and x is the input.  Plug in (x,out) = (35,-1), (128, 0), and (228,1) to get 3 equations, and solve for A, B, and C to get your x-axis mapping function.

If you'd like a more intuitive way to do *exactly the same thing*, then you can interpolate between 2 simpler linear functions like this:

```
float mapX(float x)
{
   float xmin=35, xc=128, xmax=228;
   // this line is correct for xmin and xc
   float out1 -(x-xc)/(xmin-xc);
   // this line is correct for xmax and xc
   float out2 = (x-xc)/(xmax-xc);
   // interpolate to use out1 at xmin and out2 at xmax
   return out1 + (out2-out1)*(x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin);
}
```